# Browsing a MySQL database on AWS servers

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have just installed MySQL on to my AWS EC2 server, I have also imported my existing SQL file so that my new MySQL db is now populated. I would like to be able to browse my database somehow.

In the past I used phpmyadmin and it was great, should I install phpmyadmin and then access it through my browser somehow? or am I looking down the wrong road.

Cheers

Comment: simple answer..... Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason you cant install phpmyadmin on your new EC2 server. Just remember to open up the necessary ports through amazons security group, and if you dont want the whole world to be able to access it, you can restrict the ports to only IP addresses you use.

[AWS SECURITY GROUPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)